# Output of calling a class is duplicating results(JavaFX)

Tags: java, javafx

I'm new at Java and working for an assigment I had to do the same app in CLI and GUI. 
I created 2 classes `BankingAccount`(abstract, project req) and `SavingAccount` that calculates all interest and all good banking stuff.
The I make a menu in CLI using inputs(select 1,2 or 3) the CLI is working PERFECT, but then when I try to do the "same thing" for the GUI the results are duplicated. 
For example if I write $100 in the `Deposit` field it give me a balance of $200 in the first deposit(see screenshot)
Here is also the code I'm working on:

controller.java

```
package bank;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.fxml.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;

public class Controller  {
    @FXML
    TextField txt_dAmount;
    @FXML
    TextField txt_aRate;
    @FXML
    TextArea txt_EventView;

public void createAccountBtn(){
    double amount = Double.parseDouble(txt_dAmount.getText());

    double aRate = Double.parseDouble(txt_aRate.getText());

    SavingsAccount GUIsavings = new SavingsAccount(amount,aRate);
    GUIsavings.deposit(amount);

    double currentAmount = GUIsavings.balance;
    System.out.println(currentAmount);

    txt_EventView.appendText("Your deposited: $" + amount + "\n");
    txt_EventView.appendText("Your balance is: $" + currentAmount + "\n");
}

public void CloseButtonAction(){
    System.out.println("whatever");
}

}
```

sample.fmxl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="800.0" style="-fx-background-color: #0c1446;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.2-internal" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="bank.Controller">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane layoutX="217.0" layoutY="9.0" prefHeight="583.0" prefWidth="574.0" style="-fx-background-color: #87ACA3;">
         <effect>
            <DropShadow height="1.0" radius="0.0" width="1.0" />
         </effect>
         <children>
            <TextField layoutX="166.0" layoutY="65.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="102.0">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Century Gothic" size="14.0" />
               </font>
            </TextField>
            <Label layoutX="19.0" layoutY="21.0" text="Deposit Amount">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Century Gothic" size="14.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <Button blendMode="MULTIPLY" layoutX="166.0" layoutY="105.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#createAccountBtn" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="102.0" style="-fx-background-color: #87ACA3;" text="Deposit" textFill="#11101b">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Century Gothic" size="14.0" />
               </font>
               <cursor>
                  <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
               </cursor>
            </Button>
            <Label layoutX="19.0" layoutY="70.0" text="Withdrawl">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Century Gothic" size="14.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <TextField fx:id="txt_dAmount" layoutX="166.0" layoutY="16.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="102.0">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Century Gothic" size="14.0" />
               </font>
            </TextField>
            <Button blendMode="MULTIPLY" layoutX="511.0" layoutY="467.0" mnemonicParsing="false" style="-fx-background-color: #87ACA3;" text="Save" textFill="#0d0840">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Century Gothic" size="14.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <TextArea fx:id="txt_EventView" editable="false" layoutX="12.0" layoutY="147.0" prefHeight="306.0" prefWidth="550.0" />
            <Label layoutX="301.0" layoutY="21.0" text="Annual Interest">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Century Gothic" size="14.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <TextField fx:id="txt_aRate" layoutX="413.0" layoutY="16.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="102.0">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Century Gothic" size="14.0" />
               </font>
            </TextField>
            <Button blendMode="MULTIPLY" layoutX="311.0" layoutY="105.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#createAccountBtn" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="102.0" style="-fx-background-color: #87ACA3;" text="Withdraw" textFill="#11101b">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Century Gothic" size="14.0" />
               </font>
               <cursor>
                  <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
               </cursor>
            </Button>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
      <AnchorPane layoutY="8.0" prefHeight="583.0" prefWidth="217.0" style="-fx-background-color: #175873;">
         <children>
            <Button fx:id="closeButton" layoutX="40.0" layoutY="510.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#CloseButtonAction" prefHeight="58.0" prefWidth="177.0" style="-fx-background-color: #175873;" text="Exit" textFill="WHITE">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Century Gothic" size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button layoutX="40.0" layoutY="123.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="77.0" prefWidth="177.0" style="-fx-background-color: #175873;" text="Accounts" textFill="WHITE">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Century Gothic" size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <AnchorPane prefHeight="583.0" prefWidth="40.0" style="-fx-background-color: #0C1446;" />
            <Label layoutX="61.0" layoutY="14.0" text="My Banking" textFill="#b2caf8">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Century Gothic" size="24.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <Label layoutX="103.0" layoutY="51.0" text="App" textFill="#cac5f8">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Century Gothic" size="24.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <Separator layoutX="40.0" layoutY="88.0" prefHeight="3.0" prefWidth="177.0" />
         </children>
         <effect>
            <DropShadow />
         </effect>
      </AnchorPane>
   </children>
</Pane>
```

Main.java

```
package bank;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);    
    }  

    //initialize the GUI library with a window 800x600
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("My Banking App");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 600));
        primaryStage.show();
    }    
}
```

SavingsAccount.java //do calculations in the background

```
package bank;

import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

//Define the class SavingsAccount.
public class SavingsAccount extends BankAccount {

    //Declare the required data members.
    private boolean status;

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");

    //Define the constructor.
    public SavingsAccount(double bal, double iRate) {
        super(bal, iRate);
        status = bal > 25;
    }

    //Define the method deposit().
    public void deposit(double amount) {
        if(!status) {
            if(balance + amount >= 25) {
                status = true;
            }
        }
        super.deposit(amount);
    }

    //Define the method withdraw().
    public void withdraw(double amount) {
        if(status) {
            super.withdraw(amount);
            if(balance < 25) {
                status = false;
            }
        }
    }

    //Define the method monthlyProvess().
    public void monthlyProcess() {
        if(num_withdrawls > 4)
        {
            month_charge +=1;
        }
        balance -= month_charge;
        this.calcInterest();
        if(balance < 25) {
            status = false;
        }
        num_deposits = 0;
        num_withdrawls = 0;
    }

    //Define the method get_status().
    public boolean get_status() {
        return status;
    }    
}
```

BankingAccount.java //also doing calculations in the background

```
package bank;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

//Define the class BankAccount.
public abstract class BankAccount {

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");

    //Declare the required data members.
    protected String Name;
    protected String Number;
    protected double balance;
    protected int num_deposits;
    protected int num_withdrawls;
    protected double ann_int_rate;
    protected double month_charge;

    //Define the constructor.
    public BankAccount(double bal, double rate) {
        bal = Double.valueOf(df.format(bal));
        this.balance = bal;
        this.ann_int_rate = rate;
        num_deposits = 0;
        num_withdrawls = 0;
        month_charge = 0;
    }

    //Define the method deposit().
    public void deposit(double amount) {
        this.balance += amount;
        num_deposits++;
    }

    //Define the method withdrawl().
    public void withdraw(double amount) {

        /*If the required amount can be
        withdrawn from the account then,
        perform the withdrawal operation.*/
        if(amount <= balance) {
            this.balance -= amount;
            num_withdrawls++;
        }
    }

    //Define the method calcInterest().
    public void calcInterest() {
        double mon_int_rate = (ann_int_rate/12);
        mon_int_rate = Double.valueOf(df.format(mon_int_rate));
        double interest = balance * mon_int_rate;
        interest = Double.valueOf(df.format(interest));
        balance = balance + interest;
        balance = Double.valueOf(df.format(balance));
    }

    //Define the method monthlyProcess().
    public void monthlyProcess()
    {
        balance -= month_charge;
        this.calcInterest();
        num_deposits = 0;
        num_withdrawls = 0;
        month_charge = 0;
    }

    /*Define the required
    getter and setter methods.*/
    public void set_name(String name) {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public void set_account(String account) {
        this.Number = account;
    }

    public double get_bal() {
        return balance;
    }

    public int get_no_deposit() {
        return num_deposits;
    }

    public int get_no_withdrawls() {
        return num_withdrawls;
    }
}
```

Let me know if more code is needed

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post a [mcve]. Also, as you are using FXML, please also post your FXML file. I presume that when the user clicks the _Deposit_ button, you update the `txt_EventView` control. If so, then where is the code that handles the button click? That's why you should post code that I can use to reproduce your problem.

Comment: unrelated: java naming conventions please!

Comment: _"Let me know if more code is needed"_ in fact much less is needed. MRE should be **M**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is caused by this line of the code you posted.
(Refer to method `createAccountBtn()` in class `Controller`)

```java
SavingsAccount GUIsavings = new SavingsAccount(amount,aRate);
```

According to you, the problem is that the first deposit displays an incorrect balance, so I presume that a savings account starts off with 0 (zero) balance. Hence when you create a `SavingsAccount` instance, give it a starting balance of zero. Therefore you should replace `amount` in the call to `SavingsAccount` constructor with zero, as in:

```java
SavingsAccount guiSavings = new SavingsAccount(0, aRate);
```

Note that, as per the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61400663/output-of-calling-a-class-is-duplicating-resultsjavafx#comment108619411_61400663) from [kleopatra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/203657/kleopatra), I changed the name of the variable (`GUIsavings`) so that it adheres to [java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html). Also note that there is at least one other problem with your code that I discovered, but for now I decided to only answer the question you asked.

Comment: Abra, thank you very much for you help, I really want to hear about the other issue you found.

Comment: @RolyG If you click on button _Deposit_ when field _Annual Interest_ is empty, you get an exception.

Comment: Thank you Abra, I'm aware of that, but one issue at the time, lol, my goal is to have a minimum working product right now, 
also, for some reason the call `guiSaving.balance` is not adding the amounts, I think is because every time I click deposit button, is creating a new account with 0 deposit, how can I solve this?